# Is it feasible to find n hashes that sum up to a given hash?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Consider two sets $A=\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\}, B=\{b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_m\}$;

We can calculate the hash sum of those sets:

$$HASHSUM()=(ℎℎ(a_1)+ ℎℎ(_2)+\cdots +ℎℎ(_))$$ and
$$HASHSUM()=(ℎℎ(_1) + ℎℎ(_2)+ \cdots + ℎℎ(_)).$$

Is it possible that set $$ does not equal the set $$, yet $$HASHSUM()=HASHSUM()?$$
Specifically, if $n$ (not necessarily $m$) is a small number ($<20$).

Comment: very similar question here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55185/is-it-possible-to-find-two-sets-such-that-their-hash-xor-summation-is-the-same
Main difference is + instead of xor and small n.
The other thread seems to suggest that for large m and n it is possible. It is not clear to me wether a large m alone is sufficient.

Comment: Are you really asking about *existence* or do you want a method to *find* $b_1,\dots,b_m$ given $a_1,\dots,a_n$?

Comment: @yyyyyyy I want to know if an attacker practically will be able to find 1,…,  given 1,…,.
Basically I want to use this to create identifiers for sets and I want to make sure there is no collusion.

Comment: Collision is inevitable.

Comment: What domain is your hash function mapping to? Is it the (positive integers) where you consider the integer corresponding to an output bit pattern? In that case is the + operation modular (i.e., $\pmod {2^{256}}$) for SHA-256 for example or straight integer summation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the hash length be $d$. If we consider finite groups, like addition modulo $2^d,$ this problem is well understood. Fix $k=n+m.$ If the vectors are randomly generated and form a list of size roughly at least $2^{d/k},$ there exists a solution with constant probability bounded away from zero. This is because a list of size $M$ contains $$F:=\binom{M}{k}$$ subsets of size $k,$ and thus as 
$\{a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m \}$ ranges over these subsets the function $$f(a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_m):=(a_1+ \cdots + a_n)-(b_1+\cdots+b_m)$$ hits $F$ pseudorandom points from $\mathbb{Z}_{2^d}.$

This is a $F$ balls into $2^d$ bins problem and if $F\geq 2^d,$ the probability that $f$ misses the bin corresponding to  $0 \in \{0,1\}^d$ is roughly $e^{-1}\approx 0.37.$ Taking $M=\Omega((n+m) 2^{d/(n+m)})$ is enough here. However, finding the solution is computationally more expensive.

Wagner (see [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/genbday.html) ) has a recursive binary tree based algorithm for the $k-$ XOR problem $$x_1\oplus \cdots \oplus x_k=0 \qquad (1)$$ with $k=2^s,$ with time and memory complexity essentially 
$$O(k 2^{d/(1+s)}).$$ This algorithm can be applied with addition, and will solve your problem if $k=n+m\geq d,$ since a solution will exist in that case.

Here we have $+$ instead of $\oplus,$ which is not a problem since we can use $-b_i'=2^n-b_i$ and use addition throughout. The upshot is, you need $F\geq d/(n+m).$ So if $d=256,$ and $n=20,$ you need $m\geq 236,$ and you will have complexity $$O(k 2^{d/(s+1)}).$$

**Note:** For the integer case without modular reduction, this is equivalent to a knapsack problem for which, the best algorithms are of very high complexity. Even though your outputs are in $[0,2^d-1]$ addition means your target set is much bigger. I believe the best complexity for finding a solution (if it exists, no guarantees since there is no finite domain) would then be $O(2^{(n+m)/4}),$ memory and $O(2^{(n+m)/2})$ time, from memory (Shamir Schroeppel?).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. Is there any other commutative operator that would make finding collisions harder? (multiplication?)

Comment: If the domain is finite (mod 2^n) , not really, since multiplication is a group operation. In addition any zero appearing in a product leads to a zero product increasing chances of a collision at zero.

Comment: over the integers, products are more "spread out" so yes. If the hash output is restricted to $[0,2^n-1]$ then balancing $m$'and $n$ increases probability of collision, compared to the unbalanced case. But if $n$ and hence $m$ are small the likelihood of collision will be small (you had said $n<20$.

Comment: What about EC points?  An EC public key is just a big secret random number times a generator.  So, sha256(obj[0])*G = p0.  You can compute p0,p1,p2, and -p1. p0+p1+p2+-p1 = p0+p2 ... does this have the same problems as just adding or xor the hashes?  I want to checksum a large set of database records, and subtract deleted records from the checksum. (garbage-collected blockchain, etc)