# Finding $k$ strings $M_i$ such the XOR of the $k$ hashes $H(i,M_i)$ is zero

Tags: hash, collision-attack

Let $k\ge2$ be a moderate given constant, and $H:[0,k)\times\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}^b$ be a $b$-bit given hash function assimilated to a random oracle. For example $H(i,M)=\operatorname{SHAKE256}((\underline i\mathbin\|M),b)$ where $\underline i$ is $i$ coded per ASN.1 DER.

How computationally hard is it to find $k$ strings $M_i$ such the XOR of the $k$ hashes $H(i,M_i)$ with $0\le i<k$ is zero?

Motivation is assessing the cost of an attack on [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/92203/555) protocol.

---

I see that for $k=2$ we are likely to succeed with $2^{b/2+2}$ hashes and distributed Pollard's rho with distinguished points. And that an arbitrary powerful adversary with oracle access to the hash could do with much less hash queries when $k$ becomes large, but I have a hard time quantifying the computational work.

Comment: Related (almost the same?) question and answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72596/is-it-feasible-to-find-n-hashes-that-sum-up-to-a-given-hash/72606#72606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compute $2^{b/k}$ values of the form $H(i,\cdot)$, for each $i$, then with high probability there will be *some* set of representatives who XOR to zero. Intuitively, there will be $(2^{b/k})^k$ ways to choose a representative for each $i$, so one of these ways is likely to XOR to zero. The challenge is finding such a solution efficiently.

This problem is studied by Wagner in [*A Generalized Birthday Problem*](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2002/24420288/24420288.pdf). He shows an algorithm that runs in time $O(k \cdot 2^{b/(1+\log k)})$. Indeed, the algorithm doesn't improve very much as $k$ increases, although for $k=4$ we already get $O(2^{b/3})$ which is a big jump from the $k=2$ case.

I found a [followup paper by Brakerski, Stephens-Davidowitz & Vaikuntanathan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.08821.pdf), which gives evidence that a faster algorithm is unlikely.

Also note that when $k \ge b$, solutions can be found in polynomial time via simple linear algebra. See Appendix A of [this paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7EMihir/papers/inchash.pdf).

Comment: see also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72596/is-it-feasible-to-find-n-hashes-that-sum-up-to-a-given-hash/72606#72606

Comment: Those results are all about integer sums. Do the results apply to $Z_2^b$?